# Mimic HTML form for uploading a picture

Tags: html

How do I mimic HTML form "Browse" and "Submit" buttons as done in facebook? 
My form is:

```
  <form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

So far I can just do it in the traditional way. But what I really need is: 
When the user clicks "Upload Picture" label or button or whatsoever, it mimics "Browse" button and on selecting a picture it mimics "Submit" button  events. I don't want to show the odd looking browse and submit buttons...You got my point?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+style+a+file+upload+button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used PLUpload for something similar in the past. It is primarily for larger files, but it does the browsing and masking as you desire. I've even set up the JS to auto submit once the image is selected. It doesn't take much as long as you have the basic understanding of JS.

http://www.plupload.com/